# Wake up from sleep from pressed button?

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
//This sketch is a metronome, in which each led pin shows one beat.

const int speaker = 13;  //speaker at pin 13
int ts = 6;  //highest led pin
int count = 3;  //"beat 1 pin"
const int keyPin = 11;  //button to change time signature
const int keyPinR = 10;  //button to change rhythm
const int keySwitch = 2;  //sleep mode/wake up button

//All pins below use a pull-up resistor, so the states are inverted
int buttonState = LOW;
int buttonState2 = LOW;
int switchState = LOW;
int silentState = LOW;

int bpm = 120;  //you do not need to know this, 
//it's just a variable for the potentiometer to change the tempo

int rthm = 1;  //rhythm 
volatile int pressed = 0;
long silent = p;

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);

   for(int thisPin = 3;thisPin <= ts;thisPin++)
   {
      pinMode(thisPin,OUTPUT); //initialize thisPin as an output
      pinMode(8, INPUT); //potentialmeter for changing temp    
      //Pin 9 to 11, along with pin 2, are all push buttons with pull-up     resistors
      for(int i = 9; i<=11; i++)
      {
         pinMode(i, INPUT);
         digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
      }
         pinMode(2, INPUT);
         digitalWrite(2,HIGH);       
   }    
}

void loop()
{
   turnOn();
}

void turnOn()
{
    buttonState = digitalRead(keyPin);//key for 
    buttonState2 = digitalRead(keyPinR);
    switchState = digitalRead(keySwitch);
    silentState = digitalRead(9);
    //Serial.println(switchState);
    if(switchState==LOW&&pressed==0)
    {
       sleep_enable();
       set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
       attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(0), interrupt, LOW);
       sleep_cpu();
       //Serial.println(switchState);   
    }     
    else {
       //The beat starts at pin 3, runs in consecutive pins, 
       //and ends at pin 8 at maximum
       if(buttonState==LOW)
       {  //changing time signature - up to 5 beats
           ts++; 
           if(ts==8)
           {
              ts = 3;
              //8 - 3 = 5 beats max
           } 
        }
        if(buttonState2==LOW)
        {  //changing rhythm - quarter note to eighth, then 
          //triplets and sixteenths, back to quarter notes
          rthm++; 
          if(rthm==5)
          rthm = 1;  
 }

    if(silentState==LOW){//if silent key pressed, go to silence (only LED's showing) 
    silent++;
  }

  //The RUN code 
  for(int thisPin = 3;thisPin <= ts;thisPin++)
  //LED's blinking beats (thisPin - LED pin (beat number + 2))
 { 

 for(int r = 1; r<=rthm; r++)
 {//nested loop for the rhythm      
   bpm = pulseIn(8, HIGH);//pin 8 - tempo potentialmeter
   digitalWrite(thisPin,HIGH);//each LED blinks

   pinMode(13,OUTPUT); //pin 13 - speaker 

   if(silent%2==0)//Press once, tone, press again, no tone
     noTone(13);
 else
 if(count == 3&&r==1). //first beat is higher
 tone(13,4400,80);
 else if(r==1). //downbeats slightly lower
 tone(13,2500,80);
 else
 tone(13,2200,60);  //off beats even lower
 delay((bpm-52)/rthm);    
 digitalWrite(thisPin,LOW);  //turn each off as we proceed to the next beat (LED)
 pinMode(13,INPUT);  //speaker input        
}    
count++;  //beat++

if(count >ts){//go back to count
count = 3;
}  

   }
  }
 }


void noSound()//silence the speaker
{
  noTone(13);
}

void interrupt()//this is where the sleep interrupt starts -               //how can i press it to wake up???
{
    sleep_disable();        
    detachInterrupt(0);
    if(switchState==HIGH){ 
       pressed = 1;
       Serial.println(switchState);
       turnOn(); //go back to the main functional method (?????)
     }
 }
```

Once the keySwitch button is pressed (pin 2), the arduino goes to sleep; however, the only way to turn it on is by resetting everything. How can I just wake up the Arduino, keeping every state as before the sleep interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(0), interrupt, LOW);
```

should be either

```
attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, LOW);
```

or

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), interrupt, LOW);
```

As pin 0 is not an interrupt pin. Also the button is connected to pin 2, not pin 0. `digitalPinToInterrupt(0)` would actually return `-1`.

Comment: It would be a lot more useful if you explained your apparent theory that the *wrong pin* is being monitored rather than just proposing an unexplained change to the code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for the suggestion. MikeZhou; you are welcome.